# Каталажка: происхождение слова

Tags: этимология

Как только тюрьму не называют и не называли в разные времена: и острог, и темница, и еще много как. Но все эти слова понятные. А вот меня интересует слово "каталажка" — какое у него происхождение?

Answer (score 0):

[Даль](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Dal-term-12793.htm) производит это слова от *такелаж*,

> **Катала́жная, катала́жка** *волжск.* от катала́ж, искажен. морск. такелаж, чулан во льяле расшивы, для держания снастей и припасов; это же каютка водолива; || *вост.* сибирка, блошница, каменный мешок, тюрьма, арестантская при полиции.

[Фасмер](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-5014.htm) называет *каталаж* темным словом, но Трубачев в комментариях поддерживает версию Даля:

> (Метатеза из такела́ж, как правильно указывал еще Даль2, II, стр. 96. – Т.)